# Django Variable Template Tags

Tags: python, django, templates, variables, tags

```
<p>Hello, my name is {{ name }} ! </p>
```

Where/how do I set the variable: `name = 'mike'`? I've tried putting this in the settings.py and models.py file and it does not work.

Any info of proper code to put in a .py file would be great! I've searched through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/) page but didn't see how to set a variable for retrieval.

Comment: Is this a serious question? This is an extremely basic thing which is fully covered in the tutorial.

Comment: Ouch. Yes, this is a serious question. I am new and going through the app tutorial. I did not see it mentioned in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your variable value in the view function which normally put in `view.py`

e.g.

```
def hello(request):
    return render(request, "hello.html", {"name": "mike"})
```

And you may would like to check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render to find more about how to render templates with passed variables.

You need also learn more about how does Django's URL mapping works https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/

Comment: I got it thanks. My urlpatterns were not pointing to the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

Use context processors in django. Django handles this dilemma of making some information available to
all pages with something called [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Some Code is like this,

Create a new file called context_processors.py inside your utils app directory, and add the
following code to it:

```
from project import settings
def context_data(request):
  return {
          'name': settings.name,
          'request': request
        }
```